# Fading from one SPAN to another, ending on last, jQuery

Tags: jquery

Greetings,

I am trying to fade in text spans one after another, fading each out before the next is faded in, using jQuery.

```
<p>IN
<span class="fadeText">spiring</span>
<span class="fadeText">nnovative</span>
<span class="fadeText">genious</span>
</p>
```

The spans will be set to hidden in CSS, trying fade from one span to the next and ending with the last still visible. I've tried several combinations using `$(".fadeText").each` and `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()` but cannot seem to produce this effect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[View a demo of the following here.](http://jsfiddle.net/WQYsc/16/)**

This can be accomplished by creating function that takes an index as an argument, does the fading animation on that index for the `.fadeText` elements, increments the index and calls itself if there are still elements left.  Like so:

```
var fadeNext = function ( i ) {

    var $ft = $('.fadeText'),
        timeVal = 1000;

    $ft.eq( i ).fadeIn(timeVal, function(){

        i++;

        if (i < $ft.length) {
            $(this).delay(timeVal).fadeOut(timeVal, function(){
                fadeNext( i );
            });
        }

    });
}

fadeNext( 0 );
```

EDIT: updated to meet requirement of stopping on last span, and remove incorrect recursion references.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to accomplish except for the last part- keeping the final span visible at the end rather than fading it out. In other words, INSPIRING... (fade to) INNOVATIVE... (fade to) INGENIOUS (stop)

Comment: @mVChr You don't need that timeout. You can run the fadeNext() in the fadeOut callback: `fadeOut(timeVal, function() { fadeNext(i); });`

Comment: You're right, of course, I don't know why I overlooked that.  Will edit.

Comment: This function is not recursive.

Comment: Well, it calls itself, but true it is more sequential than anything since nothing is done with the recursive call which returns nothing.

Comment: It doesn't call itself. If you logged whenever the function is entered and when it is exited you should see that it always exits before the next entry/exit pair.

Comment: Ah, because of the setTimeout in the animations the initial function thread completes before the callbacks are invoked.  Gotcha.

Comment: @mVChr Also, since you are doing a selector query on each cycle of the function, you might want to make the selector more specific. For instance: `$('span.fadeText', '#wrapper')`. That way, it'll run faster, and won't slow up the fading.

Answer (score 3):

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/xHnzP/1/

```
var spans = $('span.fadeText');

function loop(span) {
    span.fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() { 
        loop( span.next().length ? span.next() : spans.first() );
    });
}

loop( spans.first() );
```

---

Btw, the above code fades the span elements in an infinite loop. If you just want to go trough all of them once, then the code is even simpler:

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/xHnzP/2/

```
var spans = $('span.fadeText');

function loop(span) {
    span.fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() { 
        span.next().length && loop( span.next() );
    });
}

loop( spans.first() );
```

---

**UPDATE**

I didn't notice that you wanted the last SPAN to stay visible. Here is the updated code:

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/xHnzP/5/

```
var spans = $('span.fadeText');

function loop(span) {
    span.fadeIn(1000, function() {
        span.next().length && span.delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
            loop( span.next() );
        }); 
    });
}

loop( spans.first() );
```

You can see that unlike the frist two versions (above), this third version requires two nested callbacks (after the fade in, to check if it's the last SPAN, and after fade out, to call the next cycle of the function).

Also, in case you have trouble figuring this out, `span.next().length` is a check that returns true/false (acutally 1/0) based on whether or not there is at least one more SPAN after the current one.

Comment: While this did not accomplish the end result I was hoping for (ending on last span), it will prove to be quite useful in another application. Killed two birds with one stone here, thanks for your assistance and demos!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that works with your HTML as is, using a custom trigger to achieve the effect of recursion:

```
$('span.fadeText').bind('fader', function(e) {
    $(this).fadeIn(500, function() {
        if ($(this).next('span').length) { // if not the last one
            $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() { // fade out
                $(this).next().trigger('fader'); // and move to the next
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}).first().trigger('fader'); // tip the first domino
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/Ru4cv/

Comment: Very nice, works equally well. To me it's a little bit more simple to understand than the accepted answer, which is a plus. Both accomplish the end result very nicely

Comment: This one is a bit more jQuery-idiomatic, but of course there are many ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes indeed! I love asking questions here because I do learn, not just from one resource but several - it is great to get a feel for different programming methodologies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but with an extra class on your spans:

```
  $('.fadeText .one').fadeIn(1000,function() {
       $('.fadeText .two').fadeIn(1000,function() {
           $('.fadeText .three').fadeIn(1000);
        });
   });


  <span class="fadeText one">spiring</span>
  <span class="fadeText two">nnovative</span>
  <span class="fadeText three">genious</span>
```

You can adjust the 1000 duration to increase or decrease the durations.